# An error occurs only on device ( iphone & ipad ) - linker command failed

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipad

My app works well on simulator, but an error occurs only on devices.

What's the the reason of below problem?

[image]

Comment: Try a full rebuild / clean. It's possible that the a previous build has been abnormally aborted, leaving the ChannelListTableViewCell.o file corrupted or zero-size.

Comment: Hmm. Have you recently tried removing `ChannelListTableViewCell`? Check under Build Phases > Compile Sources that there are no references to `ChannelListTableViewCell`.

Comment: It works now!! Thanks PK20. I cleaned fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a full rebuild / clean. It's possible that the a previous build has been abnormally aborted, leaving the ChannelListTableViewCell.o file corrupted or zero-size.

Answer (score 0):

Remove derive data and empty the trash.